# Restrict attribute to only one property per class

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way of ensuring that an attribute marked with `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]` is used maximum once per class?

In other words, either 0 or 1 properties should be decorated with a particular attribute, never more than 1. Can this be done?

Comment: get properties of the class and count how much are marked with attribute?

Comment: @YehorAndrosov ok I should have specified something that provides compilation warnings/errors and basically gives compile time safety.

Comment: In that case you need to roll your own - eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-create-a-custom-rule-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own analyzer, compile it into dll and include in your project.

Let's start with "tests" to ensure everything works as you expect:

Single property - class compiles
[image]

Second property - class does not compile
[image]

Second attribute type - different attributes work together and compile

[image]

Attributes are counted independently - does not compile if any of those exist more than once in a class

[image]
Analyzer error message
[image]

Here is analyzer code. It goes over csharp syntax, counts properties with attributes that are marked with `AttributeUsageAttribute` and have flag `AttributeTargets.Property`

```
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;

[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class PropertyAttributeAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    private const string Category = "Usage";

    private static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(
        "PA001",
        "Multiple Properties with Attribute",
        "Multiple properties with the attribute '{0}' are found in the class",
        Category,
        DiagnosticSeverity.Error,
        isEnabledByDefault: true);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics { get; } = ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeClassSyntax, SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration);
    }

    private static void AnalyzeClassSyntax(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var classDeclaration = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
        var occurrences = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        
        foreach (var property in classDeclaration.Members.OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>())
        {
            var attributes = property.AttributeLists.SelectMany(list => list.Attributes);

            foreach (var attribute in attributes)
            {
                if (!IsDesiredAttribute(context, classDeclaration, attribute))
                    continue;
                
                if (occurrences.ContainsKey(attribute.Name.ToString()))
                {
                    occurrences[attribute.Name.ToString()]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    occurrences[attribute.Name.ToString()] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var attribute in occurrences.Where(x => x.Value > 1))
        {
            var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, classDeclaration.Identifier.GetLocation(), attribute.Key);
            context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
        }
    }
    private static bool IsDesiredAttribute(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration, AttributeSyntax attributeSyntax)
    {
        var semanticModel = context.SemanticModel;
        var attributeSymbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(attributeSyntax).Symbol;
        var attributeType = attributeSymbol?.ContainingType;

        if (attributeType is null)
            return false;
        
        var attributeUsageAttribute = semanticModel.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(typeof(AttributeUsageAttribute).FullName);
        var attributeUsage = attributeType.GetAttributes().FirstOrDefault(attr => attr.AttributeClass.Equals(attributeUsageAttribute));

        if (attributeUsage is null)
            return false;

        var validOnArgument = attributeUsage.ConstructorArguments.FirstOrDefault(arg => arg.Type?.Name == "AttributeTargets");
        var validTargets = (AttributeTargets)(int)validOnArgument.Value;
        
        return validTargets.HasFlag(AttributeTargets.Property);
    }
}
```

You have to compile Analyzer and link its dll into your project's csproj file

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Analyzer Include="C:\Users\Asus\RiderProjects\TestAnalyzer\Analyzer\bin\Debug\net7.0\Analyzer.dll"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Finally, my solution structure

[image]